# How to link multiple tables in VS2010 RDLC Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting, rdlc

I have two tables which are linking together by primary key... as an example

```
Genre
-----
GenreID
GenreDescription

Track
-----
TrackID
GenreID
TrackName
```

I want to show like the following

```
TrackID Name    Genre
1          Track1   Pop
2          Track2   Pop
3          Track3   Rap
4          Track4   Rock
```

How can I write custom SQL statements and add the fields into the database?  At the moment, I can only choose Table, View, SP and Func from the Database.  Where should I write custom SQL statements and join the required tables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new data table by joining the Track and Genre data sets on GenreID. Then add the new data set to your report and design off that.

You can easily create new data tables in designer by using your own SQL to join from existing tables.